# How to write a test for sending a PDF file to a Spring Boot REST API (application/json) with RestAssured?

Tags: json, rest, pdf, integration-testing, rest-assured

I am testing a REST API with RestAssured in Java, and I want to send a PDF file as part of a `PUT` message. The whole point of this is that I want to add validation to verify that the file being uploaded is an actual PDF, by checking the first two bytes (Magic Bytes).

The API consumes and produces JSON. I have tried printing the file as a JSON string, but that didn't come out right.

I have tried

```
.header("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed")
.multiPart("file", file, "application/pdf")
```

But the API will return a `415`, as `Content-Type` needs to be "application/json".

The test looks something like this:

```
 Path pdfPath = Paths.get("src","test","resources", "test.pdf");    
 File file = pdfPath.toFile();

        given()
            .header(X_MOCK_ID, mockId.toString())
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(json)
            .when()
            .put("/v1/customer/messages/" + messageId)
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode())
            .header(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, equalTo("no-cache"));
```

and the controller that serves the request like this:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("image/jpeg")
@Path("/bild")
@ActionFeatures(JunoService.UpdateProfile)
public void putProfilePicture(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
@Suspended final AsyncResponse response, InputStream payload) {
                

doInAuthorizedContext(request, response, context -> {
                Profile updateProfile = new Profile();
           updateProfile.setProfilePicture(toByteArray(payload));
                updateProfile.setProfilePictureMimeType("image/jpeg");
            profileService.updateProfileImage(context, updateProfile).map(result -> {              
                        return Response.noContent().build();
                    })
                    .subscribe(response::resume, response::resume);
        });
    }
```

Anyone that has done this before?

Comment: So do you mean that you are implementing a REST API endpoint using spring-mvc-rest / spring-boot , and this API has some logic to verify if the file that is PUT to it is a PDF , and you want to write a test to verify this logic ?

Comment: That is exactly right (spring-boot)

Comment: Can you add the definition of the controller which serves the request?